# D3 Data join with containers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I properly do data joins with wrapper elements on some of the levels? For instance, say I have the data `[[a,b],[x,y]]` and I want to transform it to this:

```
<wrapper1>
  <content1>
    <wrapper2>
      <content2>a</content2>
    </wrapper2>
    <wrapper2>
      <content2>b</content2>
    </wrapper2>
  </content1>
</wrapper1>
<wrapper1>
  <content1>
    <wrapper2>
      <content2>x</content2>
    </wrapper2>
    <wrapper2>
      <content2>y</content2>
    </wrapper2>
  </content1>
</wrapper1>
```

Is there a standard way to create elements with this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that creates that exact tree structure.

The `outerSelection` uses as data the outer array, which has 2 elements: `[a, b]` and `[x, y]`.

Then, the `innerSelection` uses as data the inner arrays, each one containing two elements: `"a"` and `"b"` for the first one and `"x"` and `"y"` for the second one.

Click "Run conde snippet" and look at your console (the console of your browser, which you can expand, not the snippet's one):

```js
var body = d3.select("body");

var data = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["x", "y"]
];

var outerSelection = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("wrapper1")
  .append("content1");

var innerSelection = outerSelection.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .enter()
  .append("wrapper2")
  .append("content2")
  .html(function(d) {
    return d
  })

console.log(body.node())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That makes sense! Is there a way to make this work with the update and exit selections as well?

Comment: Yes, there is, but this may be worth a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using the d3 'data' function.  As you have two levels of data here, this is how I would do it:

```
data = [['a','b'],['x','y']];

d3.select("#div1")
  .selectAll("wrapper1")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("wrapper1")
  .attr("d", function (d) {
  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll("content1")
    .data(d)
    .enter().append("content1")
    .attr("d", function (d2) {
    d3.select(this)
      .append("wrapper2")
      .append("content2")
      .html(d2);
  })
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonbleier/x04sed1q/)